# issue with absolute position of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating a photoboard in which a user can `drag-drop photos, resize it, drag it and rotate it`. Whenever a user drag-drops a new image on the board a new `div` element is created and an img tag is appended to the div element. Each div is set to float left so whenever a new image is created it will automatically be placed in its correct position. The jquery-ui plugins (resizable and draggable) are applied to the div.

A problem occurs when the user resizes any image. jquery-ui sets `position: absolute` and all image positions get distorted. After that, when we add a new image it will be inserted on the previous image. Can anybody please help me to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Get us jsfiddle to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it is difficult to know exactly what the issue is. I do have some sense of what the problem is. When using drag/resizable, the `div` will always be `position:absolute`. What you will need to do in priciple is bind an `.mouseup()` event  to any selected/dragged/dropped div that will `.addClass()` to the `div` applying the new position as well as other styles or jQuery dom manipulation. This is the approach I would take. This also allows the freedom to spice up the dropping of the image with some nice animation maybe.